# How do I use constexpr logic?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I would like to implement some `constexpr` logic in some piece of code. I am able to compile and execute this code without problem.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Starting c++ main" << std::endl;

    constexpr int val_1 = 100;
    int val_2;

    if constexpr (val_1 == 100){
        val_2 = 10;
    }
    else if constexpr (val_1 == 200){
        val_2 = 20;
    }

    std::cout << val_2 << std::endl;
}
```

But really, the `val_2` should be a `constexpr` too. How can I get `val_2` to be a `constexpr`? I tried several things, but with no success. If I declare `val_2` as `constexpr`, then I am not allowed to change its value in the `if` statement. If I do not declare the `constexpr` variable before the body of the `if` statements, then it is (as expected) not defined outside of the `if` statement.

Comment: Did You try a `constexpr` function to initialize the `constexpr` variable?

Comment: `constexpr int val_2 = val_1 / 10;`? :-)

Comment: In this case yes, but what if the logics are much more complex? I like the answer below that lets use a full fetched function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put the initializer in a ternary expression:

```
constexpr int val_2 = val_1 == 100 ? 10 : val_1 == 200 ? 20 : 0;
```

---

If your initialization logic is more complex you can write a `constexpr` function like this:

```
constexpr auto f(int val_1) 
{
  int val_2{};

  if (val_1 == 100){
    val_2 = 10;
  }

  else if (val_1 == 200){
    val_2 = 20;
  }

  return val_2;
}
```

and then:

```
constexpr int val_2 = f(val_1);
```

---

Also, note that `if constexpr` should only be used to conditionally compile code. You don't need it for regular control flow.

Comment: Oh, that is a nice one! But what if the logics are a bit more complicated and it would be nice to have a separate body function where to put a bit longer logics?

Comment: Like Robert commented, use a helper function.   `constexpr int val_2 = constexpr_function_calculating_the_value(val_1);`

Comment: @Zorglub29 Added an option for that.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an immediately called lambda:

```cpp
constexpr int val_2 = []() {
    if constexpr (val_1 == 100){
        return 10;
    }
    else if constexpr (val_1 == 200){
        return 20;
    }
}();
```

Comment: There's a nice trick happening here... `val_1` is in scope and its value can be used without having to appear in the capture list because it is `constexpr`.  You'd need to capture it if you wanted to form a reference or takes it address.

Comment: No need for `if constexpr` and no need for `else`. Also, just use `[&]()` for the lambda, which is the recommended default unless you have reasons not to.

Comment: @NikosC.: I think that using a normal `if` instead of `if constexpr` might be problematic because there's no return on the path where neither comparison is equal.

Comment: Hmmph, I cannot remove my upvote on Nikos's comment even though it was edited after I voted, to make a recommendation I don't agree with.

Comment: @BenVoigt If none of the branches are taken, you'll get a compile-time error. You don't need `if constexpr` for that.

Comment: @NikosC. I assume the `if constexpr` in the question is placeholder for something else (just ripped it from the question). `&` and no capture make no difference here (especially since it's a constant-evaluated function, so all the things it uses must be constant expressions so don't need to be captured)